# for range to send post request by using requests.Session(), it alert 'module' object has no attribute 'kqueue'

Tags: python, macos, python-requests, urllib3, kqueue

`macOS 10.12.3` `python 2.7.13` `requests 2.13.0`
I use requests package to send post request.This request need to login before post data.So I use request.Session() and load a logined cookie.
Then I use this session to send post data in cycle mode.
It is no error that I used to run this code in Windows and Linux.
**Simple Code:**

```
s = request.Session()
s.cookies = cookieslib.LWPCookieJar('cookise')
s.cookies.load(ignore_discard=True)
for user_id in range(100,200):
    url = 'http://xxxx'
    data = { 'user': user_id, 'content': '123'}
    r = s.post(url, data)
    ...
```

But the program frequently (about every interval) crash, the error is`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'kqueue'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gasxia/Dev/Projects/TgbookSpider/kfz_send_msg.py", line 90, in send_msg
    r = requests.post(url, data)  # catch error if user isn't exist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 535, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 588, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 241, in _get_conn
    if conn and is_connection_dropped(conn):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 27, in is_connection_dropped
    return bool(wait_for_read(sock, timeout=0.0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 33, in wait_for_read
    return _wait_for_io_events(socks, EVENT_READ, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/wait.py", line 22, in _wait_for_io_events
    with DefaultSelector() as selector:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/selectors.py", line 431, in __init__
    self._kqueue = select.kqueue()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'kqueue'
```

Comment: Are you using anything like eventlet, gevent, or something else that might replace the stdlib `select` module?

Comment: @sigmavirus24 Thanks, you are right. I really install gevent. I know what is key point now because your help.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to make sure gevent monkey-patches things before you import requests.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem that commonly arises if you're using something like `eventlet` or `gevent`, both of which monkeypatch the `select` module. If you're using those to achieve asynchrony, you will need to ensure that those monkeypatches are applied *before* importing requests. This is a known bug, being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/1104).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is like what your said. And I'll try to read  the issue and resolve it.